# In TFSBuild.Proj file how to <ConfigureToBuild> for Both AnyCPU and x86 Platform?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have one **MyProject.sln** project.

In that there is **two Class Library Project** and **one Window Service Project**.

Compiler build  **Class Library Projects on Any CPU** Platform and **Window Service project Build on X86** platform.

How i will set the   so that My Build execute according to selected Platform which i set in project  "MyProjectClass.csproj" file

This is Code of TFSBuild.Proj file

```
 <SolutionToBuild Condition="'$(BuildMyProject)'=='True'"
       Include="$(SolutionRoot)/MyProject/MyProject.sln">
      <Targets>Build</Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
```

Code for

$BuildFlavor = 'Release'

```
     <ConfigurationToBuild Include="$(BuildFlavor)|Any CPU">
          <FlavorToBuild>$(BuildFlavor)</FlavorToBuild>
          <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
        </ConfigurationToBuild>
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="$(BuildFlavor)|x86">
          <FlavorToBuild>$(BuildFlavor)</FlavorToBuild>
          <PlatformToBuild>x86</PlatformToBuild>
        </ConfigurationToBuild>
```

---

MSBuild try to build my MyProject.sln for both the platform. it's take more time for build. 
It's show that Build Run successfully but not generate the Binaries of Windows Service in specified $DropLocation.

But,

When I was changed my Windows Service project Build Platform from x86 to Any CPU.Now it's working properly.All three project Binaries generated and i got it in my $DropLocation But

[1] Is there any another way to solve this query?

[2] Is TFSBuild  execute only one platform for MSBuild compilation?

[3] Is it required that all the platform of subprojects are same for one .sln project?

Comment: Use the ConfigurationManager in VisualStudio and make sure that you have you projects enabled to build under the x86 configuration in the solution.

Comment: I don't have any rights for coding...only TFSBuild.proj file access rights. so please describe more. give me some proper link from where i will start to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your solution [this way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/25/solution-configurations.aspx) and change your ConfigurationToBuild to:

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="$(BuildFlavor)|Mixed Platforms">
  <FlavorToBuild>$(BuildFlavor)</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>Mixed Platforms</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

If you don't have rights to change solution file try following ideas:

1. [Building specific projects from solution with specific target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx)
2. [Try AdditionalProperties Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx)
3. Build *.csproj files instead of solution file
4. Build your projects using MSBuild tasks (override Build target)

Comment: I follow it too but same thing happen.My Binaries not generate.Something i missing in code. But this is not give me proper output.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - TFSBuild was set up in a way that it picked always the **Debug** configuration and I didn't have the permissions to change the build definition. I wanted to have the **Release** configuration to be created in the TFS build.

My solution was to edit the *.csproj files.

The prerequisite for this to work is that the **Configuration** field is empty in the related TFS build definition's build process parameters (Process / Items to build / Configurations to build). If you have the rights to modify it, you can directly select the desired configuration, save the build definition and skip the steps of the workaround below.

Steps for workaround (right-click on project):

1. Unload project
2. Edit project

Now you can edit the project file. Locate

```
    <PropertyGroup>
            <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

and change it to

```
    <PropertyGroup>
            <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
            <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

Finally, right click on the project again and select:

3. Load project

Now queue a new build and it should create it from `Release`. Likewise, you can enter any other configuration you like, for example you can create `Release_TFS` in Visual Studio and then insert it instead of Release. This will ensure you have created a separate definition for the TFSBuild before you do that.